# Exclude Branch from coverage with Gcov / Gcovr

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, gcov, test-coverage, gcovr

I'm trying to get some branches that I am not interested in testing removed from my test results, but I'm unable to get the "**EXCL_BR**" markers to work.

With this sample code

```
int32_t function(uint32_t a){
    if (a == 1) {
        a = a * 2;
    } else {
        /* GCOVR_EXCL_BR_START : these branch will never run */
        a = a * 3;
        /* GCOVR_EXCL_BR_STOP */
    }

    if (a < 25) {
        a = a + 2;
    }// GCOVR_EXCL_BR_START
    // GCOVR_EXCL_BR_STOP

    while (a > 123) {
        // GCOVR_EXCL_BR_START
    }// GCOV_EXCL_BR_STOP

    return a;
}

int32_t main (void) {

    uint32_t value = 1;

    function(value);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile and generate a GCOVR report with

```
gcc -Og --coverage -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -o main.o main.c
./main.o
gcovr --html --html-details -r . --object-directory=. -o index.html
```

And this is the report I get

[image]

I was expecting to get 100% branch coverage with my code, by "excluding" the branches that can't be hit by calling `function()` with `1` as parameter.

Is my understanding of the **EXCL_BR** markers correct? Should those unreachable branches be  tagged as hit and the report to show 100% in branches.

Comment: Branch coverage is associated with branching operations like `if` or `while`. It does not consider the code reachable via those branches. The HTML report you show is extremely helpful here because it shows exactly on which lines there are branching points that you could ignore. Line 9 (the contents of the `else`) is an uncovered *line*, but the corresponding branch happens on line 5.